# read sub header data into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with headers and sub headers shown below

```
<BC>
<-Disp->
x,-0.009 #displacement direction and magnitude
818,819,858,859,860,900,902,939,941,942,943,944,986,987,1021,1022 #nodes to read
.....
.....
</-Disp->

<-Disp->
y,0.009
818,819,858,859,860,900,902,939,941,942,943,944,986,987,1021,1022
.....
.....
</-Disp->

<-Disp->
z,-0.007
818,819,858,859,860,900,902,939,941,942,943,944,986,987,1021,1022
.....
.....
</-Disp->
<-Fix->
.....
.....
</-Fix->
</BC>
```

the thing I did was to split those data into different files and read them one by one, like

```
BCx = open('bcx.txt','r')
bcxy = BCx.readlines()
m_fixP_idx_xx = np.zeros((9, 16), dtype = int)
index=0
while index < (9):
    bcxy[index]
    idxxy=[ int(i.strip()) for i in re.split(',', bcxy[index])]
    for i in range(0, 16):
        m_fixP_idx_xx[index][i]=idxxy[i]
    index=index+1
m_fixP_idx_x = m_fixP_idx_xx.flatten()
```

it is a hard code and not able to change based on model. is there more general way to deal with it by using something like this?

```
def readbcs(infile):
    with open('bc.txt') as f:
        for disp in re.findall('<BC>(.*?)</BC>', f.read(), re.S):
            temp = disp.splitlines()
            print(temp)
```

so, I  can have numpy arrays based on whatever x, y, z in txt file, even sometimes it can be x or x, y only?

Comment: That's not a regex problem.  You should just iterate through the lines.  After seeing "<-Disp->", the next line will tell you x, y, or z.  After that, you just suck up the numbers.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` (and `np.loadtxt`) are used to read `csv` formatted files.  They can also work with anything that gives a list of strings (lines).  So they may help reading the large blocks of numbers (provided they have consistent use of delimiters and columns).  Otherwise, it's up to you to read lines and split them. Mostly that's standard python.  Once you've split it into a list of strings that represent single numbers, conversion to a numeric array is easy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726097/read-text-file-in-block-and-convert-to-numpy-array is simpler example of parsing numbers between "headers".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want your final data structure to be, but this can parse that kind of file:

```
which = None
nbrs = {}
for line in open('bcx.txt'):
    if line.startswith('<-Disp->'):
        which = None
    elif line.startswith('<-Fix->'):
        break
    elif line[0] in 'xyz':
        which = line[0]
        nbrs[which] = []
    elif len(line) < 12:
        continue
    else:
        nbrs[which].extend( int(k) for k in line.strip().split(',') )

print(nbrs)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, than you for your reply. the final data structure in my mind is several numpy arrays based on how many displacement i have. for example, 'dis_x' = [818 819 858 859 ...986 987 1021 1022] ',etc. and i tried your code and it raised a keyerror:None. do you know have to fix that? much appreciated.

Comment: The file you showed above couldn't produce that error.  If you have sections other than x, y or z, it could, of course.